# Two DNN MVC modules on the same page - conflict?

Tags: model-view-controller, dotnetnuke

I put MVC module on the same page.
Views of those modules include submit button and set of input/select controls.
I crated POST Index action to take a parameters value.
In my controller I have two actions

```
Index()
```

and

```
[POST]
Index(with_parameters)
```

When I click button in the view of one module:

It's call Index(with parameters) in second module
Action Index(with parameters) is called in module one
And just afer action Index(with parameters) the Index() action in the same controller is called.
I have no idea whats going on.
In the action with parametrs I make some logic and I want to redirect user to the certan page with additional parameters - but return Redirect(new-url-with-parameters) doesn't work and as I wrote just afer redirect the Inde() action is called again with return View(model) and user just stay on the same page without redirection.
MVC module one in the controller have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var model = ....
return View(model);
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
Index(with-parameters)
{
var url = some logic to create url
return Redirect(url);
}
```

MVC module two is almost the same.

I want to have two DNN MVC module active and working with it's own controllers and parameters